http function can't update document
i'm working on a firestore database and want to count the number of documents in a collection called "images" and then assign that value to a another document in tracking collection. The function prints the size but it doesn't update the "tracking" collection.
/* eslint-disable require-jsdoc */
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const firestore = admin.firestore();

exports.trackPortfolioImages = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  let count = 0;

  const trackingDocRef = firestore.collection("tracking").doc("imageTracking");

  try {
    admin
      .firestore()
      .collection(`images`)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        console.log(querySnapshot.size);
        count = querySnapshot.size;
        // return null;

        trackingDocRef.update({
          imagesPortfolio: count,
        });
      });
    console.log("Completed Portfolio count");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  res.send("hello");
});



Did you try to check what happens if the update operation fails?

How do you check that?

You should use a try-catch block, to log the error. Give it a try and tell me what is the error message that you get.

There is no error. I'll add it to the question.

Yes, please edit your question and show us what you have tried.

I have made the edit.

In this case, can you please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot, for both images and tracking collections?

You're ignoring the promise returned by trackingDocRef.update, which means the function might terminate before that promise resolves.  Your code needs to wait until all promises are complete before terminating.  You should read the documentation about this.
Also, you're unnecessarily using then on another promise inside as async function.  That's also unnecessary.  If you're going to write an async function, it's a lot more readable to use await on any promises in it to make sure that work completes before the function terminates.
exports.trackPortfolioImages = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  let count = 0;

  const trackingDocRef = firestore.collection("tracking").doc("imageTracking");

  const querySnapshot = await admin
    .firestore()
    .collection(`images`)
    .get()

  console.log(querySnapshot.size);
  count = querySnapshot.size;

  await trackingDocRef.update({
    imagesPortfolio: count,
  });
  console.log("Completed Portfolio count");
  res.send("hello");
});

